# Open OpenAI generated image in desired browser

Tags: python, openai-api

Everytime I let OpenAI generate an image with Python, it only displays the link to the picture in the terminal. What I would like to do is instead of only putting out the link, I'd want it to instantly open it in Firefox. I have tried converting the output into a textfile and then get a string out of it but I only got as far as creating the text file with the output inside. Here is the code I have:

```py
import os
import openai 
import sys
import webbrowser

prompt01 = input("Enter Text: ")

openai.api_key = "MYTOKEN"
response = openai.Image.create(

    prompt=prompt01,

    n=1,

    size="1024x1024",

)



d = "temp.txt"

f = open(d,'w')
print(response["data"][0]["url"], file=f)

with open('temp.txt', 'r') as file:
    temptext = file.read().rstrip()
```

Comment: ```webbrowser.open(response["data"][0]["url"])```?

Comment: I've looked through multiple Tutorials but couldn't quite find an option other than ["url"] except for a json command which didn't really work as well